# Finding Self-Intersections in Leaflet polygons using JSTS Library

Tags: javascript, mapbox, leaflet.draw, self-intersection

I'm using Mapbox with Leaflet Draw, and I would like to avoid self-intersecting polygons.

I can already specify to not allow intersections while creating the draw control, but it only works when I use the control to create a new polygon. However, if I try to edit an already existing polygon, it allows intersections over there.

I searched around and found the [JSTS Library](https://engblog.nextdoor.com/fast-polygon-self-intersection-detection-in-javascript-a405ba40dd50) which does exactly what I want, and I also found this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adm3he5k/6/) to use as an example, where it works based on the Google Maps API.

So I created my own [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishan16/ndsbp812/2/) with Mapbox based on the above two links. Here, the 'findSelfIntersects' function kicks in if it's a polygon edit, and it is not used if it is a new polygon. The idea is that, if there's an intersection, I'll show an alert to the user and cancel the edit. However, when I try to do this, I'm getting an `uncaught exception: [object Object]` error.

The error seems to be formed on this line of the findSelfIntersects function:

```
var shell = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(coordinates);
```

I checked out the coordinates returned by the Google Maps example, and that does seem similar to the coordinates I'm getting. But I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that in the Google Maps example, the starting and ending points were the same in the coordinates array, whereas mine weren't. I had missed it initially. Now I've added the below code after the 'for' loop, and it works fine.

```
coordinates.push(new jsts.geom.Coordinate(
    corners[0].lat, corners[0].lng));
```

This is an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishan16/ndsbp812/5/) in case anyone wants to use the JSTS library with Mapbox/Leaflet.